# Why double click sets my Raphael SET coordinates wrong?

Tags: raphael, drag, extjs4.2

I am using **`Raphael library`** to draw and work with objects in my **`extjs`** app. Basically I was able to find a way to `DRAG` the `SET` the following way:

```
var set = paper.set();
set.push(
    paper.circle(200,200,65).attr({fill: "orange", stroke: "black"}),
    paper.text(200, 200, buttonText).attr({"font-size": 24, "font-weight": "bold", fill: "black"})
);    

set.data("myset", set);
set.data("position", [0,0]);
var current_position = [0,0];

set.drag(   
    function(dx, dy) {
        this.data('myset').transform("T" + (this.data("position")[0] + dx) + "," + (this.data("position")[1] + dy));
    current_position = [dx,dy];
    },

    function() {
        this.data('myset').data("position",
            [this.data("position")[0] += current_position[0],
             this.data("position")[1] += current_position[1]
            ]);
    }

);
```

I found this little code in jsFiddle and modified it a little to do what I need. You can check out the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9jPy/4/). When you are dragging the item by clicking on it once, then everything seams to work. **But the problem is that when you `doublclick` on it couple of times and `play with it`/`drag`, it starts to jump around. The coordinates get messed up.**

Could you help me to find where my coordinates get messed up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by looking at this example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLtHA/)

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
var set = paper.set();
set.push(paper.circle(100,100,35), paper.circle(150,150,15));    
set.attr("fill", "orange");
set.data("myset", set);

set.drag(
    function(dx, dy, x, y, e) {
        this.data('myset').transform("T" + dx + "," + dy);
    },
    function(x, y, e) {},
    function(e) {}
);
```